# How to get JSON Object in another one in android

Tags: android, json

I have the following JSON and I want to get "temp" and "pressure" in "main" key,
but I don't know how to do that.

[this is my JSON :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sof3a.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

```
JSONObject mainJsonObject = yourJsonObject.getJSONObject("main");
float pressure = mainJsonObject.getFloat("pressure");
float tempMin = mainJsonObject.getFloat("temp_min");
float tempMax = mainJsonObject.getFloat("temp_max");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String jsonString = ... //Your json string
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
JSONObject mainObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject("main");
double temp = mainObject.getDouble("temp");
//And get other fields just like the line above.
```

---

You can also use `Gson` library which makes parsing jsons super easy.

First define your model according to your json:

```
public class JSON {
    public Main main;
    //...    

    public static class Main {
        public double temp;
        public int pressure;
        //...
    }
}
```

Then parse the json string using `Gson`:

```
JSON object = new Gson().fromJson(jsonString, JSON.class);
double temp = object.main.temp;
```

Answer (score 0):

First copy your json model to the [JsonUtils](http://jsonutils.com/) to generate your models(classes), Then you can easily use [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) to parse your json and deserialize it in to your classes.

For example you can see this [Gson Tutorial](http://www.javacreed.com/simple-gson-example/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to get root JSON object, and then get your nested "main" object.

It would be better if you provide your JSON file. But having tree structure, the code should look somehow like this:

```
//Doing it inside try/catch block, because it may throw JSONException
    try{
        //Getting root JSON object
        JSONObject rootJSON = new JSONObject(s);
        //Getting nested "main" object from root object
        JSONObject mainJSON = rootJSON.getJSONObject("main");
        //Getting custom String from JSON object, say "temp"
        String ourString = ourObject.getString("temp");
        //Then you can use it whatever way you want
        Log.e("JSONObject", ourString);
    //Handling JSONException
    } catch(JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```